# Javascript - Testing manager objects

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, bdd

I'm starting on the testing world and still have some doubts that I can't figure out. I googled for each but couldn't find anything helpful.

If I have the following object, that it's responsibility is to manage connected devices on my server, what tests make sense to write for it and how should I write these tests?

```
var devicesManager = {
    _devices: {},
    attachDevice: function(device) {
        _devices[device.id] = device;
    },
    detachDevice: function(device) {
        delete _devices[device.id];
    },
    sendCommand: function(device_id, command) {
        devices[device_id].performTask(command);
    }
}
```

These are the behaviors I need from my object so far. My questions are:

1. The object has two methods just to attach and detach devices. From what I've read I shouldn't use anything "private" on my tests, so I think I couldn't check the _devices object to see if the methods are doing what they're supposed to. As they don't return anything, how should I test these methods? Or should I not test them at all?
2. The sendCommand method is also a void returning method. I'm still confused on how to test void methods that don't change the state of my object at all. Would I be doing integration tests (instead of unit) if I spy on the device method to check if the performTask is getting called correctly?

I hope I was clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test the attachDevice and detachDevice methods, you could add another method, which tells you if a device is attached. You might need it later anyway:

```
deviceIsAttached:function(device){
    return _devices.hasOwnProperty(device.id);
}
```

You could then attach, test if deviceIsAttached, and detach.

As an idea for testing the sendCommand method, you could transform command (the parameter) into a more complex object, which knows how to test stuff (like the state in its scope). You could then make special kinds of "debug" or "test" commands, which when executed test the object/method that executes them.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. I just have one doubt about creating the deviceIsAttached and using it to test the attachDevice method. When I do this, am I going to be testing both methods in one situation? How would, for example, the test for deviceIsAttached differ from the attachDevice? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Thiago you would use the deviceIsAttached method just to expose state to the test method. Since it does something extremely simple, you shouldn't have to test the deviceIsAttached method. A full test for attachDevice/detachDevice would be this: 1. create a new device, let's say with id 4 (http://xkcd.com/221/). 2. assert deviceIsAttached(device) returns false (device is not yet attached). 3. attachDevice(device). 4. assert deviceIsAttached(device) returns true. 5. detachDevice(device). 6. assert deviceIsAttached(device) returns false.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I've read I shouldn't use anything "private" on my tests,

Not true, in my opinion. Using private stuff is a form of "white box testing" and is a legitimate technique in some circumstances (e.g. embedded systems). However you shouldn't modify anything private in your test code because that may cause things to break inadvertently.

What you also shouldn't do, ideally, is have any "testMode" functionality in your main code. That's because then you are not testing the real code but some code with modified behaviour. Instead pass objects that you want to use into objects and functions to be tested (this technique is often rather pompously referred to as "dependency injection") - that will let you pass in mock objects (see below).

> I'm still confused on how to test void methods that don't change the state of my object at all.

For these you can use mock objects.

> Would I be doing integration tests (instead of unit) if I spy on the device method to check if the performTask is getting called correctly?

If you use a real device object, yes. If you use a mock object, no.

Comment: I hadn't read anything about white box testing. I will definitely look it up. About the mocking thing, I thought even if I was mocking the other object I was doing integration test. What I understood about integration testing is testing if the communication between the two parts was being done correctly. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: I was reading the Sinon.js documentation and it says the following: `Mocks should only be used for the method under test.`. I thought that was weird since you usually mock the objects related to the object under test. What do you think? This is the url: [http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#mocks)